# Element-wise mathematical operations in multiple pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, addition, python-applymap

I have two dataframes with similar structure like follows:

```
df0
No. Name    PropNO  PropAmt
1   XYZ     -       - 
2   ABC     1077    34.90
3   GHI     -       - 
    Total   1077    34.90

df1
No. Name    PropNO  PropAmt
1   XYZ     2       0.6 
2   ABC     23      0.1
3   GHI     5       0.3 
    Total   30      1.0
```

I want output like:

```
No. Name    PropNO  PropAmt
1   XYZ     2       0.6 
2   ABC     1100    35.0
3   GHI     5       0.3 
    Total   1107    35.9
```

I have `.add()` but it also merge the Name column as well. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]
#if necessary
#dfs = [df.replace('-', np.nan) for df in dfs]
df = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby(['Name']).sum().reset_index()
```